# How to access compile Error from Visual Studio Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a add in for visual studio and I want to access compile errors from my addin.Is there any way to do it.

For example, User is compiled a project and he is getting an compiled error at that time. I want to put a help link in a error list window.

Is there any way to this. Please suggest the ways for doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Jalpesh